# Displaying input character limit inside of the input?

Tags: jquery, input, maxlength

I have set up a character limit function which displays how many more characters the input will accept. I would like to move the output to be within the `input`, floated to the right, as seen below. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Example:

[image]

```
<input name="name" placeholder="name" maxlength="120" />
<div class="remaining"></div>

function characterLimit() {
    var remaining = 120 - $('input').val().length;
    $('.remaining').text(remaining);
}
characterLimit();

$('input').keyup(function() {
    characterLimit();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9q319a4c/)

Comment: Does it need to be inside of the input borders or can it be on the right of it?

Comment: I would like for it to be within the borders of the input

Comment: You can absolutely position it there but I think the better way is to use css to kill the original borders on the input and make a fake border(wrapper div) that surrounds the input and the number. Here is an extremely simple example http://jsfiddle.net/9q319a4c/2/

Comment: this is how I would do it: simple and easy http://jsfiddle.net/7juwu6k8/

Comment: Ya, that's what I was thinking @cr0ss I was just wondering if there was some method I wasn't aware of like populating the text as a background of the input or something like that. Thanks to both of you for the suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's done by killing the original borders on the input and make a fake border(wrapper div) that surrounds the input and the number.

Here is an example from my comment http://jsfiddle.net/9q319a4c/2/

```
<div class="input">
    <input name="name" placeholder="name" />
    <span class="remaining"></span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
input {
    border: none;
}
.input {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: This is definitely thinking outside the box, thanks for this suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function(){
  
characterLimit();

$('input').keyup(function() {
    characterLimit();
});
});

function characterLimit() {
    var remaining = 120 - $('input').val().length;
    $('.remaining').text(remaining);
}
```

```css
.container{
    width:300px;
    position:relative;
}
input{
    width:100%;
}
.remaining{
      color: #5a5a5a;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;

}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<input name="name" placeholder="name" />
<div class="remaining"></div>
</div>
```

**Add these css**